# Wordpress, form in plugin, Call to undefined function add_action() in

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins

I am trying to make a plugin with form, and I can't use this form in plugin. I use: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

See all examples.

When I send form input I have notice:

> Call to undefined function add_action() in

I know it's common problem and I tried to find solution, but everything I used didn't work.

So maybe you know some website with good tutorial with really workable form in wp plugin or can help me, because maybe reason is my bad script.

WordPress 4.5.2

```
<?php

add_action('admin_menu', 'findDocMainItem');

function findDocMainItem() {

add_menu_page('findDocPlug', 'znajdź lekarza', 'administrator',__FILE__, 'findDocOpt');

add_action( 'admin_init', 'findDocOptReg' );
}

function findDocOptReg() {

register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

/***Add Subpage Create*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'findDocAddItem');

function findDocAddItem() {

add_submenu_page( __FILE__, 'Dodaj', 'Dodaj', 'administrator', 'find-doc-add',  'findDocAdd');

add_action( 'admin_init', 'findDocAddReg' );
}

function findDocAddReg() {

register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'new_option_name' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'some_other_option' );
register_setting( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group', 'option_etc' );
}

/******************************* MAIN ******************************/
function findDocOpt() {

include "conn.php";

echo '<table>';
$stmt = $addDb->get_results("SELECT * FROM citys");
//var_dump($stmt);

foreach($stmt as $row){
echo '<tr><td colspan="2" class="left"><hr /><p class="left     city">'.$row->city.':</p></td>';

$id=$row->id;
$stmt = $addDb->get_results("SELECT * FROM doctors");
foreach($stmt as $row){
                                                                            //if($row->idCity == $id){

echo '<tr><td class="doctor"><span>'.$row->surname.' '.$row->name.'</span></td></tr>';}
//}
}       

echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';    
}//end MAIN

/*******************************   ADD    *************************/
function findDocAdd() {

?>

<form action="<? echo plugins_url(); ?>/findDoctor/findDoctor.php" method="post">

<?php settings_fields( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'my-cool-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
<table class="form-table">
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">New Option Name</th>
<td><input type="text" name="new_option_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('new_option_name') ); ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
b<th scope="row">Some Other Option</th>
<td><input type="text" name="some_other_option" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('some_other_option') ); ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row">Options, Etc.</th>
<td><input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ); ?>" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
<?php
}//end ADD
?>
```

Comment: nonbody help me? why?

Comment: please, please, please HEEEEEELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLPPPPPPPPPPPPP!!!!!!!